# Changing div placement inside a defined grid keeps the original layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Problem is I have a grid defined to a sidebar area and a main area.
But when I change the order of the "sidebar" with the "main" div, the structure stays the same.
as if the structure of the html does not matter.

The HTML:

```
<div class="gridcontainer">
  <div class="sideArea">
  </div>
  <div class="mainArea">
  </div>
</div>
```

The formated HTML:

```
<div class="gridcontainer">
  <div class="mainArea">
  </div>
  <div class="sideArea">
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.gridcontainer{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    grid-template-areas:"sidebar main main";
    grid-column-gap:50px;
}
.mainArea {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    grid-area: main;
    height:600px;
}
.sideArea {
    border: 1px solid red;
    grid-area: sidebar;
    position: relative;
    height:600px;
}
```

Yet its rendered and desplayed in the same original order.
Thought maybe there a direction property like in flex-box.
But there's only grid-auto-columns
grid-auto-rows which are repsonsible for the handling of extra generated columns or raws.

Comment: since you are expliciltely defining the grid area of each element, you are explicitely placing your elements in the grid. HTML order doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

turns out like **Temani Afif** said when defining areas by name these make a static template for the order of html.
Removing:

```
grid-template-areas:"sidebar main main";
```

Fixed this